# addition in spark map transformation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a text file like this:

```
1,abc
34,bvc
98,def
43,mnl
12,xyz
54,hij

val rddtemp= sc.textFile("/tmp/tabletest.txt")

val maprdd = rddtemp.map(x=> (x.split(",")(0)+ 3, x.split(",")(1) )).foreach(println)
```

This give me :

```
(123,xyz)
(543,hij)
(13,abc)
(343,bvc)
(983,def)
(433,mnl)
```

Using `+` concatenates to the first column but I want to add to the first column giving:

```
(15,xyz)
(57,hij)
(4,abc)
(37,bvc)
(101,def)
(46,mnl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After split you've got Array[String], and + for string is concatenation. You need convert it to Int first

```
val maprdd = rddtemp.
             map(_.split(",")).
             map(arr => (arr(0).toInt + 3, arr(1))).
             foreach(println)
```